# Unable to retrieve new html code after clicking next button using selenium. URL doesn't change as well

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping https://www.coworker.com/search/turkey/izmir using selenium and beautiful soup. The html is rendered using Javascript which is why I am also using selenium. When clicking on the next button, the url is left unchanged. The driver does not obtain the new page source after the next button has clicked.

This is the code that attempts to do this:

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
spaces = []

kingUrl = f"https://www.coworker.com/search/turkey/izmir"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(kingUrl)
page = 0
count = 0
while page != 2:
    sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    # print(html)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    current_page_number = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                              '#search_results > div > div.col-12.space-pagination-outer.search-pagination-outer > nav > ul > li.page-item.active > span').text
    print(current_page_number)
    tags = soup.find_all("a", class_="optimizely-review-trigger")
    # print(tags)
    for item in tags:
        count += 1
        spaces.append(item['href'])

    page += 1
    if page != 1:
        driver.execute_script(
            "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 2300);")
        sleep(1)
    # click_button = driver.find_element(
    # by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="page-link search-page-link")
    # click_button.click()
        button = driver.find_element("xpath",
                                     '//*[@id="search_results"]/div/div[11]/nav/ul/li[4]/a')
        button.click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                            '#search_results > div > div.col-12.space-pagination-outer.search-pagination-outer > nav > ul > li.page-item.active > span').text != current_page_number)
        sleep(100)
        # wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        # (By.CLASS_NAME, "sr-only")))
        # wait.until(EC.staleness_of())
        #driver.implicitly_wait(100)
        print(current_page_number)
        # sleep(10)
```

This is a small sample with only two pages. I am trying to get it to work so that it can interact with several pages and next button clicks.

I have tried everything from explicit to implicit waits, but the page_source of the driver remains the exact same.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You really want to pull the data from the fetch requests. Selenium makes this kind of a pain but I understand selenium wire can get that

Comment: I second @pguardiario's advice. I found this [article](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html) helpful to learn about reverse engineering requests.

Comment: You should add all of the import statements. Also, your variable `spaces` is undefined.

Comment: @Übermensch Ill check this out as well thank you very much, I have edited the post to make it more clear sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code to understand the error is

```
page = 0
while page != 2:
    html = driver.page_source
    page += 1
    if page != 1:
        button = ...
        button.click()
```

The first time you arrive at `if page != 1:` you have `page=1` since just before there is `page+=1`, so the button is not clicked and `html` doesn't change. The second time you arrive at the `if` you have `page=2` so the button is clicked but then `while` is stopped since you have `while False:`.

Solution: move `page += 1` at the end of the `while` loop.